# Getting Django to log errors to a file and everything else to the console

Tags: django, logging, django-logging

Given the following logging config:

**settings.py**

```py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "filters": {
        "require_debug_false": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse",},
        "require_debug_true": {"()": "django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue",},
    },
    "formatters": {
        "django.server": {
            "()": "django.utils.log.ServerFormatter",
            "format": "[{server_time}] {message}",
            "style": "{",
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {"level": "INFO", "filters": ["require_debug_true"], "class": "logging.StreamHandler",},
        "file": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": BASE_DIR / "debug.log",
        },
        "django.server": {"level": "INFO", "class": "logging.StreamHandler", "formatter": "django.server",},
        "mail_admins": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "filters": ["require_debug_false"],
            "class": "django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {"handlers": ["file", "console"], "level": "INFO",},
        "django.server": {"handlers": ["django.server"], "level": "INFO", "propagate": False,},
    },
}
```

*Present Output*

- Console logs information- and warning-level alerts to the console
- Log file `debug.log` is created
- Compilation errors are **not** printed to the log file in production

What about this config does not allow errors to be sent to the log file?

Comment: Is your `DEBUG` setting set to `False`? Since you added`require_debug_true` to the console handler, that will block it right?

Comment: @bdbd `Debug` is being set to `True` in development, and `False` in production.